# ode-solver in complex-plane

Tags: ode, solver

For a numerical problem I'm having im trying to implement a proper ode-solver and while trial&error, I of course try RK4. In literature in complex-plane it always shows -2.78 on real-part-axis (h\lambda) and sqrt(8) on imaginary-part-axis (h\lambda).

I just can't figure out how those specific numbers occur for RK4. Is there anyone that knows?

[image: complex plane]

Comment: That is the stability region of the method, where `abs(1+z+z^2/2+z^3/6+z^4/24)<1`. Now the first is the real root of `1+x+x^2/2+x^3/6+x^4/24=-1`, and the second is where the curve `(1-y^2/2+y^4/24)+i*(y-y^3/6)` leaves the unit circle.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I should have written that I know that the encased area of the curve (mirrored at abscissa because of conjugated complex pair usually?) is the area where the stability region of solver lays. But how do you come up with these equations that you have written. Are they derived from taylorseries?

Comment: You apply the method to the linear equation `y'=lambda*y`. Then the usual explicit Runge-Kutta methods have as stability function the Taylor polynomial of the exponential function with degree of poly = order of method.

Comment: To be honest, I still cant comprehend why you get those numbers. Realpart of sqrt(f(x)) dont give me those numbers. Anyway I dont find button for giving you best answer for +reputation. Thanks for help.

Comment: I did not write an answer because the question as worked out in the comments is off-topic here. It would be on-topic on scicomp.SE or math.SE, but look there first for similar questions on the stability region/function of RK4.

Comment: The rule-of-thumb that you should derive from this picture is that you should always have `Lh<2.5` for RK4 applications to avoid totally catastrophic failures. To get reasonably accurate results you want `Lh` between `0.1` and `0.001`, `L` is a Lipschitz constant of the ODE function.